# Automatically run and return when resolving a class?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a service that is injected into my controller:

```
public function store(\App\Services\PolymorphicService $poly) {

    $poly->resolveClass();
```

Inside this service class I have some code that resolves POST data and returns a specific class.

For example:

```
resolveClass() {
     // do logic
     // return class
}
```

Is there a way to automatically run the method `poly->resolveClass();` and have that returned on the injection part:

```
public function store(\App\Services\PolymorphicService $poly) {
```

Instead of having to manually call my method?

Comment: if this class you want to return isn't a `PolymorphicService` or a child of it then no ... otherwise you could setup a binding to return what you would like

Comment: If your method requires an object of type `PolymorphicService`, it must be injected with an object of this type, otherwise the interface contract would be broken. The only way to change the type would be inside the method, manually, like you are doing.